# How to handle receiving remote push notifications properly

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, push

I have a question regarding how to handle incoming push notifications. As you would know an app can have lots of views. When receiving i would like to for example show an alert or do something else on the view that the user is in(cause i cant really know which view the user will be in when receiving the notification). Now if each view represents a swift file, then would i need to implement the same code in each swift file to handle the incoming push notifications or as i would guess there is a better design or technique to approach this?

I have been searching for a while now and all i could find was people having problems when app was in background not foreground :/

Anything would be nice, tutorial, guide , code examples. And if possible many ways to solve this so i can research them and pick whatever suits me the best.

Comment: No, setup a listener for the notification or just use the appDelegate and then just present an overlay view or do whatever you want to do - if every view has to do something different you can create a protocol to which the views conform and invoke the protocol method whenever a notification arrives

Comment: But is it seen as "good coding" to handle whatever needs to be done in the appDelegate @luk2302?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Make the appDelegate the entry point and try to delegate the functionality as early as possible, but try to avoid to have every view subscribe to the notification itself.

Comment: But my user could be in any of the views when receiving a notification? I still need every view to subscribe then right? @luk2302

Comment: No. Make all the views that want to receive notifications conform to a self-created protocol which defines some kind of function `receivedNotification`. Then check in the appDelegate wether or not the current view conforms to the protocol. If so call the method, otherwise do something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help :

Find visible view controller when receive Notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let currentViewControlelr :UIViewController = topViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!;

    if(currentViewControlelr == YourViewController()){

        //Display Alert 
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Alert"
        alert.message = "Here's a message"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Understod")
        alert.show()

        //Implement other function according to your needs
    }

    NSLog("UserInfo : %@",userInfo);
    }
```

Helper Method to get Top ViewController which is visible at the moment

```
func topViewController(base: UIViewController? ) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)

    }
    return base
    }
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'UserProfileController' & Use of unresolved identifier 'AlertView'

Comment: You have to check your controller name at place of UserProfileViewController and write your code to display alert.

Comment: im am lost right now. Why do we need that if statement to check if currentViewcontroller is "MyViewController" when i am supposed to show the alert on "currentViewController" ?

Comment: You can put alert out of if condition , if you want to show same message for all controller. If you want to show different message as per controller then you have to manage it  in if condition.

Comment: My app will show a different alert depending on the content of the push notification so that if statement wont be needed for my case thank you anyway. But if i want to show it on the currentViewController  how do i do it. im trying with this code: currentViewControlelr(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) but im getting this error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIViewController'

Comment: you want to show alert only on Visible View Controller ?

Comment: Then you have to display only alert in AppDelegate , no need to get Visible View Controller object any more.
If you want to perform specific task related to view controller then and then you have to implement above code, otherwise simply show alert view in didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: Thank you, This helped me alot